# java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, sql

```
public DialogTambah(JFrame parent, String ACTION, String NAMA) throws Exception {

    super((Frame)null,"" , true);        
    initComponents();       

    AKSI_SELANJUTNYA = ACTION;
    sId = "";
    sUserid = "";
    sPwd = "";
    sNama = "";
    sPhoneNo = "";
    sAddress = "";
    sEmail = "";
    sCrnumber = "";
    tgl="";
    if (AKSI_SELANJUTNYA == "Form Ubah") {

        try {
            Statement Update_st = DBConn.conn.createStatement();
            String SQLEdit = "select * from content where name = '" + NAMA + "' ";
            ResultSet rs = Update_st.executeQuery(SQLEdit);
            rs.next();
```

---

java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

### null

myqstn why always get null result? i've checked and no bugs.

Comment: `if (AKSI_SELANJUTNYA == "Form Ubah")` .. Aouch !! Don't compare content of Strings using `==`. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The exception says it all: your result set is empty. Run this `SELECT` statement through an SQL program and see if you get any results there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `"select * from content where name = '" + NAMA + "' ";` returns no rows ....

What line does the exception occur on?